# Basic Joint Control Question

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'm looking to write a basic joint control plugin. I'm trying to use SetJointPosition to, well, set the joint position.  The joint controller can't seem to find the joint.  After compiling the plugin, running the code gives me an error:

```
$ gazebo set_joints.sdf
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.5.0
Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Msg Waiting for master.Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.5.0
Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 142.103.111.179

Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 142.103.111.179
Warning [JointController.cc:190] SetJointPosition [my_joint] not found
```

the last line appears repeatedly.

I believe I'm doing what the [API docs](http://gazebosim.org/api/1.3.1/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1JointController.html#a3a5f360e120480d0a5e1f68a5bd4281c), and [Gwen's answer](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/249/the-setjointpositions-function-is-not-working-in/)  tell me to do.

Is there something else I have to do to make the model aware of the joint?

Here's my minimum (not) working example:
The plugin:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <gazebo.hh>
#include <physics/physics.hh>
#include <common/common.hh>
#include <stdio.h>

namespace gazebo
{   
  class SetJoints : public ModelPlugin
  {
    public: void Load(physics::ModelPtr _parent, sdf::ElementPtr /*_sdf*/) 
    {
      // Store the pointer to the model
      this->model = _parent;
      
      this->j2_controller = new physics::JointController(model);

      // Listen to the update event. This event is broadcast every
      // simulation iteration.
      this->updateConnection = event::Events::ConnectWorldUpdateBegin(
          boost::bind(&SetJoints::OnUpdate, this, _1));
    }

    // Called by the world update start event
    public: void OnUpdate(const common::UpdateInfo & /*_info*/)
    {
      // Apply a small linear velocity to the model.
      //this->model->SetLinearVel(math::Vector3(.03, 0, 0));
      
      double angle(3.0);
      std::string j2name("my_joint");  
      j2_controller->SetJointPosition(j2name,angle);

    }

    // Pointer to the model
    private: physics::ModelPtr model;

    // Pointer to the update event connection
    private: event::ConnectionPtr updateConnection;
    
    private: physics::JointController * j2_controller;

  };

  // Register this plugin with the simulator
  GZ_REGISTER_MODEL_PLUGIN(SetJoints)
}
```

The SDF:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.3">
    
  <world name="default">
    <!-- Ground Plane -->
    <include>
      <uri>model://ground_plane</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
      <uri>model://sun</uri>
    </include>
  
   <model name="box">
   <static>false</static>
      <link name="base_link">
        <pose>0 0 0.5 0 0 0</pose>
        <inertial>
          <pose>0 0 0.5 0 0 0</pose>
          <inertia>
            <ixx>1</ixx>
            <ixy>0</ixy>
            <ixz>0</ixz>
            <iyy>1</iyy>
            <iyz>0</iyz>
            <izz>1</izz>
          </inertia>
          <mass>1</mass>
     
        </inertial>

        <collision name="collision">
          <geometry>
            <box>
              <size>1 1 1</size>
            </box>
          </geometry>
        </collision>

        <visual name="visual">
          <geometry>
            <box>
              <size>1 1 1</size>
            </box>
          </geometry>
        </visual>
      </link>

      <link name="top_link">
        <pose> 0 0 1.3 0 0 0 </pose>
        <inertial>
          <pose>0 0 0.5 0 0 0</pose>
          <inertia>
            <ixx>1</ixx>
            <ixy>0</ixy>
            <ixz>0</ixz>
            <iyy>1</iyy>
            <iyz>0</iyz>
            <izz>1</izz>
          </inertia>
          <mass>1</mass>
     
        </inertial>


        <collision name="collision">
          <geometry>
            <box>
              <size>.5 .5 .5</size>
            </box>>
          </geometry>
        </collision>

        <visual name="visual">
          <geometry>
            <box>
              <size>.5 .5 .5</size>
            </box>>
          </geometry>
        </visual>
      </link>

      <joint name="my_joint" type="revolute">
        <parent>base_link</parent>
        <child>top_link</child>
        <axis>
        <xyz>0 0 1</xyz>
        </axis>
      </joint>
      
      
     <plugin name="set_joints" filename="build/libset_joints.so"/>
    </model>
  </world>
</sdf>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2105/basic-joint-control-question/) by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 175 on 2013-03-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) on 2013-03-28**:
you'll need to add joint to the joint controller by calling the AddJoint function

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-03-28**:
It's not clear to me how the AddJoint function works. I've tried it like this:   double angle(1); gazebo::physics::JointPtr my_joint = this->model->GetJoint("my_joint");   j2_controller->AddJoint(my_joint);  j2_controller->SetJointPosition("my_joint", angle); and I still get the error about the joint not being found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

this:

```
j2_controller->SetJointPosition(j2name,angle);
```

should be:

```
j2_controller->SetJointPosition(this->model->GetJoint("my_joint"), angle);
```

You could also try it like this:

```
this->model->GetJoint("my_joint")->SetAngle(0, angle_in_rad);
```

or:

```
this->model->SetJointPosition("my_joint", angle_in_rad);
```

I did not have time to test it, but if it doesn't work let me know.

Cheers,
Andrei

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2013-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-03-28**:
Thanks, Andrei.  Your first method works great.  The last one does not.

**Comment by [Chris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/269/chris/) on 2013-07-16**:
this->model->SetJointPosition("my_joint", angle_in_rad);